# CAS modification (sharing data)

Tags: cas

I want to modify CAS 3.5 to store some data in Session right after the authentication is correct. (not sure if it's the right method)

My CAS server is linked to a Kerberos one, which is connected to my Active Directory. I want to retrieve data from AD when authentication is successfully done. Then to store this data in a session attribute to easily use it in a controller.

Does someone have a clue about where to do thing in this very large CAS server project ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

CAS has a mechanism for retrieving and associating user attributes with a user's SSO session.

The implementation is based on the Jasig Person Directory project:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/PDM15/Person+Directory+1.5+Manual

You can then use the built-in services management tool to "release" those attributes to particular clients: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Attributes

Certain clients (the Java client, PHP, etc.) have built in capabilities to read and extract the attributes from the CAS server validation response.  The link above as well as the specific documentation for each client should list them.

To enable attribute loading, you need to replace the "attributeRepository" bean in your "deployerConfigContext.xml" with one of the provided PersonDirectory implementations and link it to your backing storage.